# input number don't work in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, input

i have

input type="number" pattern="[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+"/

this code work super in Chrome and Firefox, but IE don't work.

I need help. Thank you.

Comment: "don't work" = ?? Which IE? What have you done to debug it? Could you try using a full sentence with capital letters?

Comment: refer to http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number for browser support for this feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is limited support in IE and mobile browsers for this input type.

See the following sites for more information:

- http://html5please.com/#number
- http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number
- http://quirksmode.org/html5/tests/inputs_numbers.html

According to the html5please site, there is a [javascript polyfill](https://github.com/jonstipe/number-polyfill) available which handles old browsers gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft recognises HTML5's `input type="number"` in IE10 and IE11, but still has no UI support for it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number).

You'll have to wait or make your own implementation with JavaScript. You may consider that for backward compatibility with a large chunk of your potential users, anyway.